# Воспроизведение потокового аудио .NET

Tags: c#, .net, аудио, mp3

Какие для .NET есть библиотека для воспроизведения аудио (mp3) из сети во время его загрузки, то есть в потоке? NAudio не предлагать - уже второй день с ним парюсь, и постоянно нахожу какие-то костыли с багами, в виду отсутствия нормальной документации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используете WPF, то стандартный класс MediaPlayer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Open(new Uri("указываем адрес до аудиозаписи");
player.Play();
```

Но почему-то недоступно воспроизведение по https
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081956/how-to-make-a-wpf-mediaelement-play-when-its-source-is-a-https-uri

Answer (score 3):

[Creating the Windows Media Player Control Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Playing a MP3 file in a WinForm application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025626/playing-a-mp3-file-in-a-winform-application)

[libZPlay](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libzplay/)

[irrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/features.html)

also:

[Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb324224(v=vs.85).aspx)

[winmm.dll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STNAOk_IiqE)

Comment: irrKlang, честно говоря, не посоветую... Т.е. скачать - проиграть файл с диска - это оно может, быстро. Более сложные задачи - очень гемморойно с ней работать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать ещё [Bass.NET](http://www.un4seen.com/)

Comment: Работали с ней?

Comment: Да, работал. В принципе вариант не плохой. В том числе, для достаточно сложных задач.
Правда он имеет и свои тонкости. В прочем, ИМХО, ни одно технологическое решение без них не обходится.

Comment: есть возможность смены позиции для воспроизведения в буферезированном стриме?

Comment: Возможность смены позиции при потоковом воспроизведении имеется. К слову, раз уж заговорили о тонкостях, у Bass.NET есть достаточно подробная [документация](http://bass.radio42.com/help/). Она поможет разобраться в деталях.

Comment: Все бы ничего, если бы не лицензия

Comment: Для freeware разработки лицензия бесплатная. Если же планируете выпускать коммерческое ПО, тогда действительно придётся платить.

Comment: На сколько правильно я понял из условий использования, используя рекламу в моем freeware ПО, я должен иметь лицензию

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, при наличии рекламы это ПО уже, по сути, не freeware, а AdWare. Вообще в столь неоднозначной ситуации, на Вашем месте, я бы задал  вопрос разработчику чтобы поставить все точки над i.